# How do I generate numbers according to a parabolic distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a function that plots the distribution of ions emitted as a function of the angle of emission. To simulate the emission I would like to sample values according to the function, but I'm struggling to do so.

The function is:
$$
\frac{3}{2\Theta_{0}}\left[1 - \left(\frac{\Theta}{\Theta_{0}}\right)^2\right].
$$
$\Theta_0$ is a constant, but for my purposes, it will be equal to $18$.
I've tried to use the inversion method, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: What do you mean you can't get the inversion method to work?   What goes wrong?

Comment: I think its because the function isn't normalised, or I'm misinterpreting something. This is the result of integrating and then inverting the function. https://i.gyazo.com/d426df30c02cba0be7037c761e0dc1cc.png I want to be able to input a randomly generated value between 0 and 1 and get a value between 18 and - 18 according to the distribution. Have I achieved it here if I subtract 18 from the output of the function?

Comment: I don't understand.  If your function is $F(x)$ then $\int_0^1 F(x)\,dx=1$ so the support of your distribution is, presumably, $[0,18]$.  Now, $\int_0^x F(t)\,dt$ is a cubic, so inverting it is unpleasant, but perfectly possible (at least numerically).

Comment: Is the inversion I put in the previous picture correct?

Comment: As I said, I am not clear on the support of your distribution.  I thought it was $[0,18]$  Thus, to generate a random sample from your distribution, I'd pick a uniform random number $x_0$ on $[0,1]$ and then choose $x_1\in [0,18]$ according to $\int_0^{x_1}F(t)\,dt=x_0$.  But maybe I have misunderstood your intent.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for but my resulting function doesn't seem to work correctly. At no point does it give a value below 18, which is meant to be the maximum number that can be sampled.

Comment: Well, $\int_0^x F(t)\,dt=\frac x{12}-\frac {x^3}{11664}$, barring error.  So...if, say, your uniform random was $x_0=.616$ then we want to set that cubic to $.616$,  yielding $x_1=7.8991$ No problem.

Comment: Again, I don't suppose there is a terribly useful closed form for the inverse to the cubic, but Newton's method (or simple interpolation) is fine.

Comment: Thankyou so much I understand why it wasn't working now. How would you go about implementing newtons method into a program? And how do I avoid unwanted roots?

Comment: Depending on how much accuracy you need, I wouldn't bother.  I'd precompute the values of that cubic for, say, $\{0,.01, .02, \cdots, 18\}$ and then linearly interpolate as needed.  If extreme precision is required then I'd still use the interpolator to generate a seed, but usually interpolation is good enough.

Comment: Okay brilliant that's what I'll do, thankyou very much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{{3 \over 2\theta_{0}}\pars{1 - {\theta^{2} \over \theta_{0}^{2}}}\dd\theta = \dd\xi}\
\mbox{where}\ \xi \sim {\cal U}\pars{0,1}\ \mbox{with}\
\pars{~\xi = 0 \implies \theta = 0}
\\[5mm] & \mbox{Then,}\ {3\theta \over 2\theta_{0}} - {\theta^{3} \over 2\theta_{0}^{3}} = \xi \implies \pars{\theta \over \theta_{0}}^{3} - 3\pars{\theta \over \theta_{0}} + 2\xi = 0
\\[5mm] & \implies \bbx{\color{#44f}{{\theta \over \theta_{0}} =
2\sin\pars{\arcsin\pars{\xi} \over 3}}}.\quad
\substack{\mbox{With this expression,}\\[1mm]
\mbox{each}\ \ds{\xi}\mbox{-random value in}\ \left[0,1\right)\\[1mm]
\mbox{generates a random value of}\
{\ds{\theta} \over \ds{\theta_{0}}}.}
\end{align}

[image]

[image]